# Como limitar um input de acordo com a variavel?

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Tenho 2 campo como mostra abaixo abaixo :

```html
 <div class="col-md-4">
                      <label for="descricao">Valor título </label>
                          <div class="input-group">
                            ﻿<span class="input-group-addon">R$</span>
                            <input type="text" id="entr_valorMoeda" class="form-control valor" value="<?php echo $conta->ENTR_ValorMoeda;?>" readonly >
                            <input type="hidden" class="valor"  name="entr_valorMoeda" value="<?php echo $conta->ENTR_ValorMoeda;?>">                                        
                          </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="col-md-4">
                      <label for="descricao">Valor baixa </label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                          <span class="input-group-addon">R$</span>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control valor" id="valorBaixa" name="valorBaixa" value="<?php echo $valorBaixa;?>">
                          <input type="h﻿idden" name="totalBaixas" value="<?php echo $totalBaixas; ?>">                                        
                        </div>
                  </div>
```

Aonde o primeiro campo me reporta um valor de banco de dados e o 2 replicar esse mesmo valor mas o primeiro campo esta bloqueando nao podendo alterar e o segundo eu posso alterar, ai que eu queria saber como eu faço pra quando eu for alterar esse segundo o mesmo não passa do valor da varialvel. ﻿﻿

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Deixe entender você tem dois campos 

Você tem 2 campos. o valor de ambos vem do banco de dados.
Um você quer bloqueado. o outro você quer editar.
Sem alterar o valor do anterior. é isso ?

Comment: Você acertou em partes, o valor de ambos são igual e vem do banco mas um já o primeiro e bloqueado e o segundo pode editar só que o segundo o valor nâo a ser digitado não pode passa dor valor do primeiro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma sugestão é comparar os valores ao alterar o segundo input com `keyup`. Se o valor digitado for maior que o do primeiro input, o código aplica no campo o valor do primeiro.

Para isso é preciso deixar os valores no formato correto, onde deve ter apenas um ponto separando as decimais (ex., `25066.77`). Para isso eu uso 2 replaces, o primeiro removendo os pontos dos milhares (se houver) e o segundo substituindo a vírgula por ponto. Também é necessário usar `.parseFloat()` para converter em número float (com decimais).

No exemplo abaixo eu coloquei uma máscara para formatar o valor monetário no campo:

```js
// máscara para exemplificar
$("#valorBaixa").maskMoney({
   allowNegative: true,
   thousands: '.',
   decimal: ','
});

$("#valorBaixa").on("keyup", function(){
   
   // número mascarado
   var entr_valorMoeda = $("#entr_valorMoeda").val();
   // número formatado para comparação
   var entr_valorMoeda_num = parseFloat(entr_valorMoeda.replace(/\./g, "").replace(",", "."));
   // número mascarado
   var valorBaixa = $(this).val();
   // número formatado para comparação
   var valorBaixa_num = parseFloat(valorBaixa.replace(/\./g, "").replace(",", "."));
   if(entr_valorMoeda_num < valorBaixa_num){
      // se o primeiro valor for menor que o segundo
      // forço o segundo a ser igual ao primeiro
      $("#valorBaixa").val(entr_valorMoeda);
   }
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-maskmoney/3.0.2/jquery.maskMoney.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-4">
   <label for="descricao">Valor título </label>
   <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon">R$</span>
      <input type="text" id="entr_valorMoeda" class="form-control valor" value="25.066,67" readonly >
      <input type="hidden" class="valor"  name="entr_valorMoeda" value="<?php echo $conta->ENTR_ValorMoeda;?>">                                        
   </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">
   <label for="descricao">Valor baixa </label>
   <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon">R$</span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control valor" id="valorBaixa" name="valorBaixa" value="25.066,67">
      <input type="hidden" name="totalBaixas" value="<?php echo $totalBaixas; ?>">                                        
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Flw man era isso mesmo ficou show, gostei dessa sua sugestão de compara os dois.

Comment: Man me tira uma duvida, se agr  tiver um 3 campo aonde agora o valor do 2 não poder ser maior do que o (1 - 3) tem como ?

Comment: Rapaz, aí vc tem que fazer uma nova pergunta.

Comment: Ta novo kkk flw

Answer (score 0):

você não quer deixar passar o valor da variavel quando cadastrada no banco? ou quando o usuário for alterar dentro do input?
Você pode fazer isso dentro de um if.

```
if($variavel >= $variavel2){

echo "Não deixo cadastrar no banco"

}else{echo "ela é maior, então não pode alterar";}
```

Á logica é mais ou menos essa.

Comment: E mais ou menos essa mas nao e pra aparecer mensagem nem nada e só limitar o valor do campo mesmo.